# Refresh token Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been trying to refresh token when an access token is expired but I still got 401 error 
Here is my interception code

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefresh = false;
  constructor(private tokenService:TokenService,
              private authenticationService:AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let accessToken = this.tokenService.getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken){
      request = this.setHeaders(request, accessToken);
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) =>{
        console.log(err.status);
        console.log(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
        if(err.status === 401 && err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
          console.log("CALLING!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
          return this.handleAuthorizationError(request, next);
        }
        return throwError(()=>err.error.message);
      })
    );
  }

  private setHeaders(request:HttpRequest<any>, token:string){
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }

  private handleAuthorizationError(request:HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler){
    console.log("CALLING HANDLE")
    if(!this.isRefresh){
      this.isRefresh = true;
      return this.authenticationService.refreshToken(this.tokenService.getRefreshToken()).pipe(
        switchMap((res)=>{
          this.isRefresh = false;
          this.tokenService.setAccessToken(res.accessToken);
          this.tokenService.setRefreshToken(res.refreshToken);
          return next.handle(this.setHeaders(request, res.accessToken));
        })
      )
    }else{
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
}
```

TokenService

```
export class TokenService {
  constructor() { }

  
  getAccessToken(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("accessToken") == null){
      return "";
    }
    return localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  }

  getRefreshToken(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("refreshToken") == null){
      return "";
    }
    return localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
  }

  setAccessToken(token:string){
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
  }

  setRefreshToken(token:string){
    localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", token);
  }

  clearToken(){
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
    localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
  }
}
```

AuthenticationService

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public authenticate(request:AuthenticationRequest){
    return this.http.post<AuthenticationResponse>(`${AUTH_API}/auth/authenticate`, request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err)=>{
          console.log("Error handled by Service..." + err.status)
          return throwError(()=> new Error(err.error.message));
        })
      );
  }

  public logout(){
    return this.http.get(`${AUTH_API}/auth/logout`);
  }

  public currentUserAccess():Observable<User>{
    return this.http.get<User>(`${AUTH_API}/auth/current-user`)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log("Error handled by Service..." + err.status)
          return throwError(()=> new Error("fix later!"));
        })
      );
  }

  public refreshToken(token:any):Observable<AuthenticationResponse>{
    return this.http.post<AuthenticationResponse>(`${AUTH_API}/auth/refresh-token`, {
      "refreshToken": token
    }).pipe(catchError((err)=>{
      console.log("Error handled by Service..." + err.status)
      return throwError(()=> new Error(err.error.message));
    }));
  }
}
```

Request and Response Interface

```
export interface AuthenticationRequest{
  username:string;
  password:string;
}

export interface AuthenticationResponse{
  accessToken:string,
  refreshToken:string
}
```

So I set the access token expiry 1 minute and refresh token is 30 days for testing purpose, when the access token expired I refresh the page and I got 401 error. I still don't know why! 
[image]

Comment: Did you check if data in the `localstorage` get updated after the `refreshToken()` api call? does `tokenService.getRefreshToken()` return the correct value?

Comment: @giacomoto yes my refreshToken() work well but seems like it does not reach switchMap part in refreshToken()

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day debugging, I have finally identified the possible cause. I use Spring Boot as my back-end 
My JWTFilter

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(username!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){ //
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            var isTokenValid = tokenService.getByToken(jwt)
                    .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
                    .orElse(false);
            if(jwtService.isValidToken(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

My JWTFilter (updated)

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        String jwt=null;
        String username = null;

        if(authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            try{
                username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }
        if(username!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){ //
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            var isTokenValid = tokenService.getByToken(jwt)
                    .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
                    .orElse(false);
            if(jwtService.isValidToken(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```